# "It was an April" vs "It was in April"

Tags: prepositions, indefinite-article

> "It was an April afternoon. And the warm breezes of  approaching
>   summer had sent everyone, including Grandfather, indoors".

The above sentences are from the story '*Adventures in a Banyan Tree*' by the Indian English writer Ruskin Bond. (The context of the story is a school boy's summer vacation excitements and experiences, which he narrates after the vacation. The summer vacation falls in April and May)

Based on these sentences, a question for editing came in an examination. But in the question, they used only "April" instead of "April afternoon" as shown below:

> "It was (a) **at** April. The warm breeze of the approaching summer (b)
>   **have** sent everyone indoors including grandfather".

Now my question is about the answer to (a): can it be **an** as in the actual sentence in the story?

Or,

Should it be **in**, the preposition before the name of a month?

Answer (score 3):

"An" is associated with the noun "afternoon", with April modifying it as an adjective. It was *an afternoon in April*; an *April afternoon*.

If we were just referring to April generally, "it was April" would be correct, as we are not referring to a particular time within that month.

Comment: *It was an afternoon in April; an April afternoon.*  It's okay. What about *it was in April*  as in "It was in April (a strange thing happened)" ?

Comment: *It was in April **when / that** a strange thing happened.* Or, reversed, *a strange thing happened in April*.